# Show there is a closed interval $[a, b]$ such that the function $f(x) = |x|^{\frac1{2}}$ is continuous but not Lipschitz on on $[a, b]$.

Tags: calculus

Hi guys I was given this as an "exercise" in my calculus class and we weren't told what a Lipschitz is so i really need some help, heres the question again:

Show there is a closed interval $[a, b]$ such that the function $f(x) = |x|^{\frac1{2}}$ is continuous but not Lipschitz on on $[a, b]$.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) is your best friend.

Comment: Intuitionally, Lipschitz function does not have `infinite slope'. However, $f$ has a infinite slope at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the interval $[0,1]$, then clearly $f(x) = x^{1/2}$ is continuous.

Can you show that $f$ is not Lipschitz on $[0,1]$? (Hint: Use the Mean-Value theorem on a closed sub-interval of $(0,1/n]$)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is Lipscitz on $[0, 1]$. Then there is a positive constant $L$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)\leq L|x-y|$ for all $x$, $y\in[0, 1]$. In particular, for $y=0$ we have $\sqrt{x}=|f(x)-f(0)\leq L|x|$. This implies that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\infty$. We arrive at contradiction.